# Bearer Token Invalid Token

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

want to use bearer token in postman but i got invalid token when using bearer but wihout typing it it works fine.

```
const auth = async (req , res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '');
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'thisismynewcourse');
    console.log('decoded', decoded);
    const user = await User.findOne({_id: decoded._id , 'tokens.token': token})
    console.log('token ',token);
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error()
    }
    req.token = token;
    req.user = user
    next();

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).send({error: 'please authenticate'})
  }
}

router.get('/users/me', auth ,async (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Bearer token is formatted like:

`Bearer XXX` // "Bearer" + whitespace + token

You forget a whitespace on your replace()

Replace `.replace('Bearer', '');`

by this `.replace('Bearer ', '');`